# How to add facebook button on website

Tags: facebook, web

I want to add one a small facebook button to my website, something like this:

[image: http://www.amigaz.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/facebook-logo.png]

or

[image: http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT33TNF_OgD9oATALBY8qXhUp-rbhomlIf73O2j9rEWaipLDzGb]

I can work out how to get a 'Like Box' or 'Page badge' on the facebook help pages, but I'd rather have a smaller, neater little button.

Try and explain slowly and clearly- I'm not a programmer!

Jeny

Answer (score 1):

I think creating image with link on it should be more than enough.

```
<a href="link_to_your_facebook_page>"><img height="height_of_image" width="width_of_image" src="link_to_image" /></a>
```

replace everything in "'s with the numbers/links you need